# Nuxt js app build still loading constantly

Tags: nuxt.js

I have made 2 new app with Nuxt.js

they are working well with `npm run dev`

But the static file create with `npm run build` and `npm run generate` is loading constantly

the console say "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

I don't know how to fix it.

My nuxt.config.js

```js
export default {
  // Disable server-side rendering: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/ssr-mode
  ssr: false,

  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'À Bicyclette',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },

  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
  ],

  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },

  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your nuxt.config.js file.

Comment: Your nuxt.config looks fine to me, did you try npm run generate and locally serving it with http-server ?

Comment: Yes i have run those files with Xamp and a real server

Comment: Aince you do have a new page open, it may be related to some lifecycle hooks. Idk exactly what is happening but we need the code of `/pacifique`. Btw, since you're using `static`, there is no need to `yarn build` here, `yarn generate` is enough.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! I got the issue with your feedback. Nuxt app need to be at the root of the server to work (problem of link between files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback! I got the issue with your feedback. Nuxt app need to be at the root of the server to work (problem of link between files).